# Getting "Connection refused" error while trying to connect and empty the Amazon s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created one Amazon s3 bucket via api and I am able to upload file successfully. But while I am trying to empty the bucket with same credentials, I am getting  exception as "*com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection refused*".

My code snippet is like below..

```
AWSCredentials awsCredentials =
            new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,secretKey);
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);
    s3client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
```

Stack trace is

```
INFO  [2016-04-22 14:50:52,885] com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient: Unable   to execute HTTP request: Connection refused
! java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
! at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
! atjava.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnectna:1.7.0_79]   
! at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) 
! at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
! at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625)    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:409)com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:134)
```

Not sure whether I am doing the right thing or is there any proxy issue.

Comment: What endpoint are you trying to connect to?

Comment: "s3.amazonaws.com" is the endpoint @ataylor

Comment: Can you connect to `https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com` manually?

Comment: I am getting below error while accessing the url manually...@ataylor                   <Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>7368FFEBB9A8ABEA</RequestId>
   <HostId>
KvsO+8afQJIKxRXwhrAZh4V0EvAbyvSwb8c0DkY7e6xrtjgqHTIU+Sc421mmC/TT0iw+jAm7VYM=
  </HostId>
</Error>